# VB6/VBA Iterate through all predeclared class objects

Tags: excel, vba, vb6, ms-office

Can I dynamically iterate over all Predeclared objects?

This is a problem I've been dealing with for a while now. Ideally I'd iterate through all classes and check if they implement some interfaces. If they do then execute some code on them.

Currently I have to provide some array of classes to execute e.g:

```
ClassesToCheck = Array(Task_Class1,Task_Class2,Task_Class3,Task_Class4, ...)

Dim klass as object
For each klass in ClassesToCheck
  if klass.implements(ITask) then
    Call klass.execute()
  end if
next
```

In an ideal world I would do something like this:

```
Dim klass as object
For each klass in GET_PREDECLARED_CLASS_OBJECTS_FROM_MEMORY()
  if klass.implements(ITask) then
    Call klass.execute()
  end if
next
```

I don't expect there is any easy way to do this, but I have done a little research/exploration of the VBA runtime memory... I think it should be possible and have found some VB6 examples of this using the VBA6.DLL, however, unfortunately this DLL is not provided in Microsoft Office natively. However, the VBA6.DLL is likely 'compiled into' Microsoft Office itself. So the methods/fields should also be held in memory somewhere, you just need to know where they are using pointer math (is my theory)

I don't suppose anyone has had any experience with this?

Comment: There are similar questions on Stack Overflow and they mention Microsoft's TypeLib Information Object Library (tlbinf32.dll), which allows you to programmatically inspect COM type information at run-time.

Comment: Jan Karel Pieterse seems to have done something like this. See: https://jkp-ads.com/articles/ObjectLister.asp?AllComments=True

Comment: I've not tried it myself, just wanted to mention that avenue as something that could be looked into...

Comment: @rickmanalexander This is a neat looking project! Wouldn't want to register the type library dll though. I'd prefer to call those directly from the DISP IDs. But very neat anyway, thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: @Sancarn I wouldn't want to either, lol, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute makes your `Class1` identifier automatically refer to a global-scope object by that name, e.g. `UserForm1` is the name of a class module (one with a designer, but that part is irrelevant), *and* it's the name of a global, automagic object spawned by VBA at runtime, and the compiler knows `Class1.DoStuff` is legal *because* it knows `Class1` has `VB_PredeclaredId` set to `True`.

Thanks to the work and contributions of Wayne Phillips (vbWatchDog) and other contributors, [Rubberduck taps into this internal API](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/ComManagement/TypeLibs/VBETypeLibsAccessor.cs#L38).

As shown in the linked code (C#), you can get ahold of the `ITypeLib` for a VBA project from its `References` collection, by turning the pointer into a struct with this specific layout:

```csharp
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct VBEReferencesObj
{
    IntPtr _vTable1;     // _References vtable
    IntPtr _vTable2;
    IntPtr _vTable3;
    IntPtr _object1;
    IntPtr _object2;
    public IntPtr _typeLib; // <--- here's the pointer you want
    IntPtr _placeholder1;
    IntPtr _placeholder2;
    IntPtr _refCount;
}
```

In VBA that would be a user-defined `Type` that might look like this:

```
Public Type VBEReferencesObj
    vTable1 As LongPtr
    vTable2 As LongPtr
    vTable3 As LongPtr
    object1 As LongPtr
    object2 As LongPtr
    typelibPointer As LongPtr '<~ only this one matters
    placeholder1 As LongPtr
    placeholder2 As LongPtr
    refCount As LongPtr
End Type
```

Once you have the pointer to the `ITypeLib`, you should be able to get the VBA project's type library.

From there, you'll want to iterate the types, and from there determine whether the type's `TYPEFLAGS` has `TYPEFLAG_PREDECLID` turned on (we do this [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/ComManagement/TypeLibs/TypeInfoWrapper.cs#L123)).

Obviously this is **a lot** of extremely crash-prone trial-and-error coding, and I wouldn't recommend doing any of this, but in any case, it's *possible*, if not adviseable.

Feel free to study [Rubberduck.VBEEditor.ComManagement.TypeLibs](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/ComManagement/TypeLibs) namespaces.

Comment: Somehow I figured it might be you replying to this topic! Thanks a lot! If I manage to implement this I'll definitely be building it into an OS library. I guess from there I'll need to use `ITypeInfo::CreateInstance()` to create a new instance of the class?

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you know what functions the other vTables point towards?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Also if you figure out how to create a VBA class instance, I'd like to know... this could be leveraged into something as crazy as... an IoC container for VBA code!

Comment: @Sancarn I bet the `COM` genius (Wayne Phillips) either knows or could figure it out. His idea of injecting a precompiled COM object that snoops run-time memory to grab call stack info is utter genius.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Will let you know. I suspect it will involve calling `ITypeInfo::CreateInstance()` then using `IUnknown::QueryInterface()` to get the `IDispatch` interface. Anyway will inform you if I figure it out :)

Comment: We did try that though =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to leverage the `tlbinf32.dll`, to get class info directly from memory, however, If you stuck with you current approach, but used a collection of objects instead of an array of objects, you could do the following:

```
Private ConditionalExecution()

    Dim PredeclaredClasses As Collection

    Set PredeclaredClasses = New Collection

        PredeclaredClasses.Add Task_Class1
        PredeclaredClasses.Add Task_Class2
        PredeclaredClasses.Add Task_Class3
        PredeclaredClasses.Add Task_Class4

    ExecuteIfImplementsInterface PredeclaredClasses

End Sub 

Private Sub ExecuteIfImplementsInterface(ByVal Classes As Collection)

    Dim klass as object

    For each klass in classes
        If TypeOf klass Is ITask Then klass.execute()
    next

End Sub
```

Ofcourse this would be contigent on the fact that these classes would have to be instantiated via "dimming" them as the interface they are implementing like so:

```
Dim bar As ITask

Set bar = New Task_Class1
```

SideNote: If you were wondering, Yes I suck at coming up with method names.